# Differentiating under the integral sign - Error in the attempt?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function. Define $F(x)=\int_0^xf(u)(x-u)du$.

Then, by the first fundamental theorem of calculus, we know that if $g$ is a continuous function and $G(x)=\int_0^xg(x) dx$, then $G'(x)=g(x)$.

> Applying the same for $F$, we get : $F'(x)=f(x)(x-x)=0.$

**Whereas, if we solve in the following manner:**

$F(x)=x \int_0^x f(u) du - \int_0^xf(u) \cdot u ~du$

> $\implies F'(x)=x f(x) + \int_0^x f(u) du - xf(x) = \int_0^x f(u) du$

Why is there a discrepancy of an answer in both the methods? I know that I am making a conceptual error somewhere. I would really appreciate if someone could provide a rigorous understanding of the error. Thanks a lot for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up notations. In the the theorem you stated you should write $G(x)=\int_0^{x} g(t)dt$. This gives $G'(x)=g(x)$. The integrand $g(t)$ cannot be of the form  $g(t,x)$ for this theorem to be applicable.  So your first answer is wrong. Your second answer is the right one.

[To apply this theorem  $x$ can only appear as the upper end point of the interval (with lower end point constant);  $x$should not appear inside the integral sign].

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that if $$g(x)=\int_{L(x)}^{U(x)} f(x,t) dt$$, then By Lebnitz Rule
$$g'(x)= U'(x) f[x, U(x)]-L'(x) f[x, L(x)]+ \int_{L(x)}^{U(x)} \frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x} dt$$
Mind the last part.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: You are welcome.